# How to access sda4 device/directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, mount

Our camera DVR is not recording anymore. The disk is full and the vendor has not been helpful in freeing up space. I am trying to figure out why the primary disk is full. I've tried accessing it through cd /mnt/dev/sda4, but as you may have guessed, that did not work. Also, there is no GUI enabled for this device. When trying to startx, I get "X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting."

How can I get access to the /dev/sda4 directory (or device) to see what's eating my space? And after doing so, how can I pull up directory/file space without having to wait so long for the du command to compute?

Filesystem    Size    Used    Avail    Use%     Mounted on
/dev/sda1      65G     20G      42G      32%     /
udev           7.9G    12K      7.9G     1%     /dev
tmpfs          3.2G     300K     3.2G     1%     /run
none           5.0M       0     5.0M     0%     /run/lock
none           7.9G     84K     7.9G     1%     /run/shm
/dev/sda3       26G     5.0G     20G     21%     /storage
tmpfs 3.0M 176K 2.9M 6% /tmp/tmpfs
/dev/sdb1 7.5G 5.5G 2.1G 74% /media/cfrestore
**/dev/sda4     3.5T     3.4T     0     100%     /mnt**
/dev/sdc 3.6T 309M 3.4T 1% /media/4fc55b9f-e2cd-4c88-a1d0-5a94ac81dce4

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS"

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the mount command is basically:

```
mount /path/to/disk/in/dev /path/to/folder
```

The command you probably ran was:

```
mount /dev/sda4 /mnt
```

This means the disk is mounted in /mnt, not /mnt/dev/sda4.

To answer the question, checking disk space is accomplished via du:

```
umount /dev/sda4
mkdir -p /sdcard
mount /dev/sda4 /sdcard
cd /sdcard
du -csh *
```

If you want a list of all files, remove the s from the last command.